# Creating margin in full width footer

Tags: html, css

I am creating a full width `footer` with `margin`, but it seems like when I add the `margin` it overflows. How can i avoid this?

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7be35f4v/1/)

```css
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin 40px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2em;
}
footer .left_div {
  float: left;
}
footer .right_div {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="left_div">This is a long test</div>
  <div class="right_div">This is another text</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that'll result in the desired effect.  You should probably remove the `width: 100%` and instead add `left: 0; right: 0;` in addition to correcting the typo pointed out by choz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're specifying a width of 100% so when you add the margins then it becomes 100% + 40px on each side making it 80px wider that the window.

There's a few ways to fix it, you can use `calc` for the width so subtract the extra margin on the sides:

```
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px); /* 40px on each side = 80px */
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Or even easier remove the width property and add `left` and `right` properties to stretch the element without directly messing with the size:

```
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Still has the `margin 40px` typo.

Answer (score 3):

You're missing `:` in your css declaration. And yes, this is fatal.

```
margin 40px;
```

be

```
margin: 40px;
```

Your `footer` is positioned at a specified position relative to its closest positioned ancestor or to the containing block. As MDN says about [Absolute Position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position). And your there's no relative closest parents to it. Which in your case, in the fiddle, `width: 100%` will take the width of `iframe` which is `700px`.

But, you can have the workaround like this,

```
footer {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 40px;
  bottom:0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Here's the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7be35f4v/9/)

Comment: @JavaCake I was wondering that myself. But I figured that the `100% width` is taken from the iframe parent. And I could replicate the same both in jsfiddle and codepen. But it should've worked fine locally.

Answer (score 2):

from my experience the best way is remove `width: 100%` and use `left: 0; right: 0;`

```css
footer {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  margin: 40px;
  font-size: 2em;
}

footer .left_div {
  float: left;
}

footer .right_div {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="left_div">This is a long test</div>
  <div class="right_div">This is another text</div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Reset default `margin` in `body` and add `box-sizing:border-box` to `footer`,

because you are applying `margin` and using `position:absolute` you need to use `calc()`

plus, you have a typo on `margin 40px`, should be `margin:40px`

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
footer {
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 40px;
  width: calc(100% - 80px);
  font-size: 2em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: red
}
footer .left_div {
  float: left;
}
footer .right_div {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="left_div">This is a long test</div>
  <div class="right_div">This is another text</div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Is my approach stupid, or can it be done with something that does not involve calc?

Comment: I can give you another way, If I know your requirements

Comment: you can also use margin: 40px 0;  so you dont have to involve calc

Comment: @JavaCake and has to be fixed on bottom? or can be right after the content that you should have?

Answer (score 0):

add 
  left:0; to the footer css :)

Answer (score 0):

It will overflow as margin increases the space from outside the div or block. If you want to hide the overflow then use `overflow: hidden`.

If you want to show all the data with margin then you should reduce width and then apply margin.

It is not worth to apply margin on div/block instead use padding. Padding increases from inside.